# Form alter hook in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, hooks

I have created a content type in which I have a field that is a select box.
Now I want to change all the default values of that select box.

I know `hook_form_alter()` will work this, but I have no idea on how to change this.
Is anybody able to give me an idea?

Comment: Did you add that field using your own module, or CCK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adjust the values of the form element to your needs. Check this http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#select to see how selects ar build using FAPI.

Comment: This is correct, but if the field is a CCK field, there is a easier way. Also, answers that contain a little more than a link are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange.